# Not receive callback in success block of ajax submit options

Tags: php, ajax, ajaxsubmit

I have an piece of code here, it's just an ajax options which I use to pass to my **$(form).ajaxSubmit(submit_ajax_options)**

```
var submit_ajax_options = {
            url: init_param.server_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: { agents_data : agents },
            dataType: 'json',
            timeout: 30000,
            beforeSubmit: function( formData, jqForm, options ){
                
                console.log('before submit');

                form_loader.fadeIn();
                
            },
            success: function( response, status, xhr, $form ){
                
                console.log('success callback');

                form_loader.fadeOut();
                if(response.status == 'ok'){
                    
                    create_box('success', response.msg);
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        window.location.href = response.redirect;
                    }, 2000);
                }
                else{
                    create_box('danger', response.msg);
                }
            },
         }
```

And this is my process code on my server (PHP):

```
<some processing code here>

$response['redirect'] = $redirect_url;
$response['status'] = 'ok';
$response['msg'] = "successfully";
//output data jsone
echo json_encode($response);
```

when I run as debug on my server, code ran ok without any mistake, but in my js code at client, I don't receive anything callback in my success block of submit_ajax_options (I don't see the logging string in my browser console, although the logging string in beforeSubmit block was printed)

I really have no any idea for this issue. Anybody can help me about my situation. really thank you a lots

Comment: you have to `return` it.. `return json_encode($response);
`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if it helps you

1. ```php
   $response['redirect'] = $redirect_url;
   $response['status'] = 'ok';
   $response['msg'] = "successfully";
   //output data jsone
   echo json_encode($response);
   exit; // add exit so it stops execution and you can see the data in response
   ```
2. decode your JSON response

   ```php
   var data = JSON.parse(response);

   console.log(data.status)
   ```